# Why is $-2-3(-1)^{2/3} = -5$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Have I gone mad? Consider this:

$$f(x) = -2-3x^{\frac {2}{3}}$$

Why would $f(-1) = -5$?

Doesn't make sense to me. $f(-1)$ equals $1$ when plugging it in on my calculator. But in my book and when plotting this using google's plot feature (just google this: "`-2-3(x^(2/3))`" and hover over $-1$), I get $f(-1) = -5$?

Comment: When plugging in on your calculator, perhaps you computed $-1^{2/3}$ instead of $(-1)^{2/3}$ ... mathematicians (and apparently your calculator) interpret $-1^{2/3}$ to mean $-(1^{2/3})$

Comment: Well assuming you mean real value of $x^{2/3}$ when you have that it's equal to ${x^2}^{1/3}$ which is equal to $1$ when $x=-1$ then you have that it's equal to $-2-3=-5$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How do you define $(-1)^{2/3}$? That is the crux.

Answer (score 0):

Likely, you will want to consider:
$(-1)^{2/3}=\sqrt[3]{-1^2}=\sqrt[3]{1}=1$ or 
$(-1)^{2/3}=(\sqrt[3]{-1})^2=(-1)^2=1$.
In either case, from here $f(-1)=-2-3(1)=-5$.

Comment: Note that $(-1)^{2/3} = e^{2\pi i/3}$ is also valid and yields a complex result.

Answer (score -2):

We can write  $-1^\frac23$ as $(-1^2)^\frac13$  which is equal to $\sqrt[3]1$ which is 1. So $-2 - 3(1) = -5$.

Note that it doesn't matter what you do first whether the cube root or the square. $\sqrt[3]{-1} = -1$ and ${(-1)}^2 = 1$. So you still get the same answer $-5$

Comment: While you "get the answer" this way, note that $(-1)^{2/3} = e^{2\pi i/3}$ is also a valid choice and yields a complex result.